# Python 3 - print if after specific time

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

Is there anyway in Python 3 to check the hour and if its after a certain hour do an action (like print "it is the afternoon)?

This is what I'm done already:

```
import time
import datetime


now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")
hour = datetime.hour().strftime("%H")

if (hour > 12):
    print("it is the afternoon")

print(now)
```

If I run it I get an AttributeError.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Good first question.  One suggestion for future questions - when you post the error, give the complete text of the error.  I.e., for this question, the text was: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hour'`.  No big deal in this case, but in other situations it can make it much easier to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just suggest the following:

```
import time
import datetime


now = datetime.datetime.now()

if (now.hour > 12):
    print("it is the afternoon")

print(now.strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: nice way of cutting down on the text, afraid I don't have any reputation to upvote you with.

Answer (score 1):

The `datetime` module has no `hour` method, so `datetime.hour()` will crash.

Perhaps you meant to do:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")
hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
```

Comment: that would be why it wasn't working them. Will admit I'm not very good at python still.

Answer (score 0):

You can access hour directly from `datetime.datetime` object:

```
if (datetime.datetime.now().hour > 12)
    print("Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're calling `datetime.hour()` where `datetime` is a module, not an object of `datetime`. You probably meant something like this:

```
hour = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H")
```

But strftime returns `str`, to a `int` (which is comparable to another `int`), so you need:

```
hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H"))
```

Which is definitely an overkill. Here are a simplest method

```
hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
```

Or with `time` module:

```
hour = time.localtime().tm_hour
```